# How to transpose and group by CSV data using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

**I have to Transpose and Group CSV data values**

**The Actual data which I have *data_input.csv*** :

[image]

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"data_input.csv")
data.transpose()
```

Expected Output what i need is :

[image]

How i can put all the particular countries together , suppose i have three columns with India so i have to keep all the column value starts with India together followed .

Comment: can you copy and paste the data into your question, rather than an image?

Comment: @DavidErickson -  I have taken the snap of the exact data that i have .

Comment: copy and paste it, so people can copy and paste the data into their python interpreter to test it instead of manually typing it in.

Comment: @DavidErickson - Please find the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/11A2pD1K2n5fS19BXqYvfqWYRQwTX23XA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv(r"Book1.csv")
>>> df = data.set_index('Date')
>>> data
        Date  India- Actual  Australia- Actual      ...       India- Virtual  Australia- Virtual  USA- Virtual
0   31/10/19        21209.0             3292.0      ...               3656.0              1245.0        1525.0
1  1/11/2019         2060.0             2600.0      ...               3396.0             35008.0        2389.0
2  2/11/2019         3652.0             2874.0      ...               3456.0              2356.0        4561.0
3  3/11/2019         3696.0             9658.0      ...               3652.0              6325.0        3652.0
4  4/11/2019        35008.0             6589.0      ...               8745.0              9658.0        8520.0
5  5/11/2019         7894.0             9647.0      ...               8898.0              9874.0        3029.0
6        NaN            NaN                NaN      ...                  NaN                 NaN           NaN
7        NaN            NaN                NaN      ...                  NaN                 NaN           NaN

[8 rows x 7 columns]
>>> df
           India- Actual  Australia- Actual  USA- Actual  India- Virtual  Australia- Virtual  USA- Virtual
Date
31/10/19         21209.0             3292.0       2587.0          3656.0              1245.0        1525.0
1/11/2019         2060.0             2600.0       3652.0          3396.0             35008.0        2389.0
2/11/2019         3652.0             2874.0       4578.0          3456.0              2356.0        4561.0
3/11/2019         3696.0             9658.0       6925.0          3652.0              6325.0        3652.0
4/11/2019        35008.0             6589.0       2899.0          8745.0              9658.0        8520.0
5/11/2019         7894.0             9647.0       3652.0          8898.0              9874.0        3029.0
NaN                  NaN                NaN          NaN             NaN                 NaN           NaN
NaN                  NaN                NaN          NaN             NaN                 NaN           NaN
>>> df.T
Date                31/10/19  1/11/2019  2/11/2019  3/11/2019  4/11/2019  5/11/2019  NaN  NaN
India- Actual        21209.0     2060.0     3652.0     3696.0    35008.0     7894.0  NaN  NaN
Australia- Actual     3292.0     2600.0     2874.0     9658.0     6589.0     9647.0  NaN  NaN
USA- Actual           2587.0     3652.0     4578.0     6925.0     2899.0     3652.0  NaN  NaN
India- Virtual        3656.0     3396.0     3456.0     3652.0     8745.0     8898.0  NaN  NaN
Australia- Virtual    1245.0    35008.0     2356.0     6325.0     9658.0     9874.0  NaN  NaN
USA- Virtual          1525.0     2389.0     4561.0     3652.0     8520.0     3029.0  NaN  NaN
>>>
```

Note: Please share sample data to avoid sample data creation time and to understand problem statement more properly.

Comment: Please find the data - https://drive.google.com/file/d/11A2pD1K2n5fS19BXqYvfqWYRQwTX23XA/view?usp=sharing